# macosx not recognizing held down keys on boot

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, boot, boot-camp

I'm running fully updated snow leapord on a new model imac.

I am unable to boot into macosx. I do have build 7600 of windows 7 that the computer will automatically boot to.

I do not have the bootcamp manager on windows 7.

The computer is not recognizing any held down keys when I try to either boot from cd or force macosx boot or anything.

How can I get the computer to load up osx?

Comment: What type of keyboard?  USB? Bluetooth?

Answer (score 2):

If you install the Boot Camp Utility, you can use it to set the startup disk to the Mac OS X volume.

Comment: I can't find the bootcamp utility. only an upgrade from vista

Comment: If you insert the Mac OS X DVD while Windows is booted up, you will find the Boot Camp Utility installer on it.